# Transferring multiple files from ftps server to Liferay Portal

Tags: ftp, liferay, sftp, ftp-client

We have a client FTP server where they uploads multiple number of pdf files in /dev directory. The pattern of pdf files are [ORGANAIZATION_NAME]_CR.pdf . We are retrieving these files and uploading it our Liferay document library based on the [ORGANAIZATION_NAME].

We are facing issue while retrieving the multiple files using a single ftp connection. First time it retrieves the list of files of current directory (/dev) and uploads in Liferay document library. But when it trying to retrieve the second file, it returns the length of files as zero and throwing error as Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error:
Connection closed without indication.

Please refer the below code.

```
public static void importReports() {
    InputStream is = null;
     System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
     FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient();
    try 
    {

            // Store file on host
             ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
           // Connect to host
            ftpClient.connect(hostname);
            int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            if (!ftpClient.login(loginname), PortletProps.get(password))) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            // Set protection buffer size
            ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
            // Set data channel protection to private
            ftpClient.execPROT("P");
        try{
              List<Organization> orgList = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizations(-1, -1);
              for (Organization organization : orgList) {
                                String folderPath ="/dev";
                                String ftpfileName = organization.getName();
                                String ftpFilePath = folderPath+StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH+ftpfileName;
                                ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(folderPath); 
                                // Enter local passive mode
                                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                                ftpClient.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);
                                FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(folderPath);
                                for(FTPFile file : files)
                                {
                                    if(file.isFile() && file.getSize() > 0 && file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ftpfileName))
                                    {

                                        try{
                                            is = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(ftpFilePath);
                                            if (Validator.isNotNull(is)) {

                                             ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
                                        }catch(SocketException se)
                                        {
                                            LOGGER.info("SocketException  :"+se.getMessage());  
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                // Logout
                ftpClient.logout();
                // Disconnect
                ftpClient.disconnect();
        }
        catch(PortalException e)
        {
            LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.info(ioe.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            // Logout
            ftpClient.logout();
            // Disconnect
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update the code, it seems closing brackets are missing from your code. Thanks.

Comment: Seriously System.exit() when you can't connect to ftp? Using OrganizationLocalServiceUtil sounds like this runs within Liferay, which runs within an application server - handling application level problems with System.exit()?? Really?? It's not your browser that states the closed connection due to this, right?